# Does the @ObservedObject debounces requests to rerender the view if many @Published properties changes in a short period?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

In swiftUI I can add as many `@Published` properties as I wish inside an `ObservableObject` class and every time I change a @Published value, a "signal" is sent to the publisher objectWillChange of the class.

It means that If I receive a network request with a json and set the value of multiple `@Published` properties inside that class multiple messages `objectWillChange.send()` will be sent, and since the view responds to that publisher via `@ObservedObject` I have a question regarding performance,

Does the `@ObservedObject` debounce the request to rerender the View if many signals are sent in a short period of time? for example, when receiving a json with 10 fields I might send 10 messages to ask the view to rerender,

Or will the View actually rerender 10 times and I should be more careful in how I expose the data via `@Published` properties? (maybe storing a single object with all the values?)

Comment: It is does not debounce

Comment: You can test it by adding `let _ = Self._printChanges()` in the view's body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it doesn't matter how many times `objectWillChange` is called, SwiftUI will only flag the View's body for recomputation once. Essentially it coalesces all of the notifications into one action. That is why it uses willChange and not didChange.